# Custom view for realm map clusters

Tags: swift, mkmapview, realm

As far as I read realm docs for map clustering there is a class `ABFClusterAnnotationView` which have few properties : `count`, `color`, `countLabel` but I can not find anywhere `image` for annotation. Is it the way to `override` this with adding an `image` property ? I manage to add `images` by using default annotation iside `mapView` delegate method but from there i can not manage of count of clusters. I would like to change the image only where there is only pin with 1 value on the map.

So there is nothing tricky, simple setting an image for an annotation :

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        let annView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "test")
        annView.image = myImage

        return annView
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO image property is not overridden. But anyway you have still several options:

1. Do not use `ABFClusterAnnotationView`. (use e.g. `MKAnnotationView`)
2. Use `FBAnnotationClusterView`,
   set `FBAnnotationClusterViewConfiguration` and in template use `FBAnnotationClusterDisplayMode.Image(imageName)`
3. Use different library - https://github.com/efremidze/Cluster

Ad 1)

```
override func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        switch annotation {
        case _ as MyAnnotation:
            // use MKAnnotationView
            let reuseId = "Pin"
            return mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView ?? MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        case let fbAnnotation as FBAnnotationCluster:
            let reuseId = "Cluster"
            let clusterView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) ?? FBAnnotationClusterView(annotation: fbAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId, configuration: FBAnnotationClusterViewConfiguration.default())
            return clusterView
        default:
            return nil
        }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thats cool answer! But it will not hit case with `MyAnnotation` becouse from a default all of annotations became from Realm library.